# Create a query in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table that is called P_sighting. I has these columns (Site_ID, Dive_Num, Genus, Species)
I want to make a query that create a list of species that have been sighted on every single dive at the Site_id # 3014.

Answer (score 0):

If Site_ID is of type NUMBER, use this query

```
select Species
from P_sighting
where TO_NUMBER(Site_ID) = 3014
```

If Site_ID is of type VARCHAR, use this query

```
select Species
from P_sighting
where TRIM(Site_ID) = '3014'
```

Comment: @AbuMohanad If neither of these work I recommend going [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) and building your schema so we can assist further. The above answers are correct but you aren't giving us enough information.

Answer (score 0):

If your site_ID is a long/number, you should be able to form a query simply with

```
select Species from P_sighting where SITE_ID = 3014
```

Comment: Thanks but this will give me every species which sighted on Site_ID 3014. I want to create a list of species that have been sighted on every single dive at the Site_id # 3014. which means each dive should have this species.